# Using LWJGL without making too much JNI calls

Tags: java, c, jogl, lwjgl

I want to draw a model with `LWJGL` and I know that on calling each `glVertex` method, a `JNI` call occurs, that is time consuming. Since I have the model in a file, I want to use just one `JNI` call (add a native method to `LWJGL` library), and at the native side, get my model vertices from the file (using c language) and draw them all (avoiding a `JNI` call per vertex).
So, I want to change `LWJGL` library source and add a function to do this. 
my question is, does this feature available in `LWJGL`, `JOGL` or in any possible java bindings for `openGL`?

Comment: A JNI call can take around 10 ns.  How many times are you calling it?

Comment: I think near one million times.

Comment: So it could take 10 ms. Its worth testing how long it takes on your machine (it can vary quite a bit) Some type of bulk load would make sense so it is reasonable to check it doesn't have such a feature already. Certainly JOCL can take whole arrays of int/float/double as arguments (not quite the same thing)

Comment: In newer OpenGL standards glBegin()/glEnd() and related functions are deprecated (thought still available in the compatibility profile). Using them is painfully slow compared to modern alternatives as they involve resending the same information to the gpu every time you draw an object.

Comment: @josefx Deprecated? so what's the new alternative way? can you give any examples?

Comment: @KeyhanAsghari the new alternative are the Vertex Buffer Objects mentioned in Michael Slades answer - they store the Vertex data in GPU memory and only changes to the data have to be send to the gpu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Vertex Buffer Objects to store your vertex data, and make calls to draw as many vertices/triangles is practical with just one call to [glDrawArrays](http://docs.knobbits.org/opengl/sdk2/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml), [glDrawElements](http://docs.knobbits.org/opengl/sdk2/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) or similar.

[This page](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_Vertex_Buffer_Objects_%28VBO%29) explains how to use them in LWJGL.

Note that the LWJGL version of the OpenGL docs is rather lacking.  Check the [OpenGL official site](http://opengl.org) for the C versions which explain their functionality very well.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the OpenGL glVertexPointer function which in LWJGL is wrapped by [glVertexPointer (link)](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/GL11.html#glVertexPointer%28int,%20int,%20java.nio.DoubleBuffer%29).

BUT!

if you are worried about the speed of a mere JNI call, then why not reconsider doing this in c/c++ instead?

Later Edit: [documentation for glVertexPointer](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml)

Comment: because the other parts of my program is written in Java and SWT.